# In django channels recieve,Updation on database is not working

Tags: django-models, django-channels

routing.py

```
route("websocket.receive", im_active, path=r'^/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/stream/$'),
```

## consumer.py

```
def im_active(message, slug):
    post = json.loads(message['text'])['post']
    current_user = VisitorInfo.objects.get(user_id=user)
    current_user.active=True
    current_user.save()
```

The value of the active field is not updated in the backend.If I again fetch the active value in `im_active` function, like:

```
new_user = VisitorInfo.objects.get(user_id=user)
print(new_user)
```

gives `True`, but it doesn't update in the DB.

Comment: Did you work this out?